# What is a good tutorial for using ORMLite with SQLite and Android

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I am looking for a good introductory tutorial on how to use ORMLite with SQLite and Android.  A qucick google search did not produce any usefull information.

Comment: https://github.com/amityadav1984/ORMLite-Tutorial

Comment: https://horaceheaven.com/android-ormlite-tutorial/

Answer (score 47, accepted):

- [Table of contents](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_toc.html#SEC_Contents) for OrmLite docs. Which are pretty good by the way.
- [ORMLite samples](http://ormlite.com/android/examples/) for android
- Blog post on ORMLite: [Using an existing SQLite database](http://www.b-fil.com/blog/2011/01/20/android-repository-ormlite-existing-sqlite-db/)

Comment: The OrmLite docs I think are the best for starting with OrmLite. They are simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 32):

I think that this tutorial is very good:
http://logic-explained.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-ormlite-in-android-projects.html
since it also includes a demo project that can be downloaded from GitHub
https://github.com/justadreamer/WishListManager