# Integrating ormlite-4.9 with sqlcipher-2.08

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite, sqlcipher

I'm integrating ormlite-4.9 with sqlcipher-2.08. I've googled around but, I didn't succeed.
I also saw Mr. Gray's answer([How can I use ORMLite with SQLCipher together in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9180906/1278748)) about integration. I tried by his answer. However, I guess it was for older versions of ORMLite and SQLCipher which has different packages than mine which is downloaded from http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android.

Can someone explain me a bit in detail?

Comment: I know nothing about ORMLite, but to follow his instructions, just change `info.guardianproject.database.sqlcipher` to `net.sqlcipher.database`.

Comment: refer to my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13170232/745270

Answer (score 3):

I just add the same problem than you. The problem  is that you have to change the `ormlite-android.jar` code to make it work with the `SQLCipher` lib. So what you have to do is :

1. Download the `SQLCipher` latest version from [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/sqlcipher/SQLCipher+for+Android+v3.1.0.zip) or directly from the [website](http://sqlcipher.net/open-source/)
2. Unzip the folder then copy it in to your project.
3. Add the zip in the assets folder to your build path.
4. Download the `ormlite-core` code for 4.46 (you can try higher but i don't guarante that it is going to work), you can do it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ormlite/files/releases/com/j256/ormlite/ormlite-core/4.46/ormlite-core-4.46.jar/download).
5. Add the library to your libs folder
6. Download this git project : https://github.com/d-tarasov/ormlite-android-sqlcipher
7. Copy the source folder in your project
8. The package of ormlite classes have changed so just correct it.

And it should work :) Let me know i you have any problem with that !

Comment: My friend @Eliott, this question asked 2 years ago.  Thaks for replaying, I will try use this.

Comment: No worries, it is just when i see your question and i was looking for an clear answer i didn't found it so I decided to put it for futur people which gonna have the same problem :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is quite old thread. But I had to go the same way recently. I've read two threads in search for solution: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176768/how-can-i-use-ormlite-with-sqlcipher-together-in-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771251/integrating-ormlite-4-9-with-sqlcipher-2-08).

1. I followed ge0rg's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14774778/955107), it almost worked, were some problems and I have to replace methods inside my code (I wanted to avoid it).
2. I did what Eliott Roynette suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24775373/955107) and it worked good except I needed to add one method to Helper class to accept password and I did it.
3. I wanted to exclude code into lib to have more smart solution instead of code mix, so I build lib/module separately.

And now I have [solution](https://github.com/sierpito/demo-ormlite-with-sqlcipher) that works (you can clone working demo from GitHub). Placing my answer into both threads to help others in the future.