# queryforall() is not working in the case of ormlite and sqlcipher

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, ormlite, sqlcipher

i have used the sqlcipher and ormlite together. imported the net.sqlicipher and net.sqlicipher.database packages in my project and downloded the ormlite-android-sqlcipher.jar. and i have given the password to DatabaseHelper class constructor, so when i am inserting the data it is working fine. but while fetching the records queryforall() is throwing java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery exception. but i have that method in sqlitedatabse class. how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLCipher does not have a `queryForAll` method on the `SQLiteDatabase` class.  You can use the `rawQuery` to send a SQL query which will return a `Cursor` of your results.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but  please look into this Link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176768/how-can-i-use-ormlite-with-sqlcipher-together-in-android. in this link the second answer says that sqlcipher is working with ormlite.and also create method is wrking in ormlite why queryforall is not working@ Nick