# ORMLite request using SQLCipher

Tags: android, ormlite, sqlcipher

I have a problem with making request using these both libraries. I wanted to get all queries from my table Table_events with .queryforall() but then I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105470/queryforall-is-not-working-in-the-case-of-ormlite-and-sqlcipher) thread and tried to make query with rawQuery but it offers only queryRaw(). The request looks like this:

```
private Dao<Table_Events, Integer> tEventDao;

public DAOManager(final DatabaseHelper databaseHelper) 
{
    this.tEventDao= GettEventDAO(databaseHelper);
}

public String[] Getall()
{       
    GenericRawResults<String[]> rawResults = null;

    try 
    {
        rawResults = tEventDao.queryRaw("select * from tableEvents");
    }  
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultArray;

}
```

any ideas how make a query?

Answer (score 0):

Your `GettEventDAO` function is returning an object that conforms to the `Dao` interface of ORMLite.  You would need to make sure the implementation of ORMLite is able to interface with SQLCipher for Android which would typically return a Cursor representing the resultset of your query.